# Validation error only when app User Interface is set to Persian language

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple MVC application where I save GPS(lat,long) coordinates in a table. The app is in 2 languages (English and persian). Latitude and longitude can be saved without any error when the UI is on English language, but when I change the language to Persian and try to enter same lat and long format it gives validation error (ex: the value ’32.23453 ’ is not valid for latitude and same for longitude). I am using bootstrap-rtl  for Persian language. and when I enter an integer value it accepts.

The error:
[image: The error]

Model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Latitude", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Company))]
 public double latitude { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Longitude", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Company))]
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.latitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">                
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.latitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.latitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.longitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.longitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.longitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

It's very weird , I tried changing the data type to decimal but faced same error. Your help is much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

are you saving the lat-lng values in some kind of database  table ? if yes then can you change the data type to nvarchar and see if it helps.

to better understand how to get started with Globalization and Localization
you may go through the below tutorials

[Globalization & Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
[Globalization in ASP.NET Core](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/globalization-in-asp-net-core-3c70379d1e7f)

*Pls like and vote if your issue is resolved*.

Comment: yes I use SQL database and save lat-long in a table.